How can I view a history of SQL queries in SQL Server Management Studio?
Is there a way in SSMS 2008 R2 to view the history of queries run on a certain database? For example, I do an update on some row in a table. I then want to see a record in some query history table showing that update.
The SQL Server Logs under "Management" don't show me anything. Is this possible?
Thanks!

There is no such history table in SQL Server.

Why are you using such an old version? And the logs would likely only contain data if you were using commitment control. COMMIT/ROLLBACK etc when writing SQL transactions.

Some add-ons to ssms support query history. You can also sometimes collect recent ran queries and query plans from various dm-views.

Thanks everyone. I downloaded SSMS Tool Pack and the Search Local SQL History option and the Show Current Window History option do the trick.

To add to what @JGFMK is talking about, SQL Server 2008 (R2) reached end of life in 2019; over 5 years ago. You really need to get onto a supported version. 2016 onwards are in externed support minimally, with only 2022 and 2019 (for a few more months) still fully supported.
